# How to differentiate the function $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ at $ a=(a_1,a_2)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> How to differentiate the function $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ at $ a=(a_1,a_2)$?

$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\Vert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h\Vert}{\Vert h\Vert}
&=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\Vert (h_2+a_2,h_1+a_1)
-(a_2,a_1)-(0,a_1h_1)-(a_2h_2,0)\Vert}{\Vert h\Vert}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\Vert (h_2,h_1)-(a_2h_2,a_1h_1)\Vert}{\Vert h\Vert}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\Vert (h_2(1-a_2),h_1(1-a_1))\vert\vert}{\Vert h\Vert}
\end{align}
$$

At this point I don't think I can do anything because I don't know what $a_1$ and $a_2$ are. If I knew they were between $[-1,1]$, I could use squeeze theorem but I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You are trying to *linearly* approximate the function
$$
f(x,y)=(y,x)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Should  $Df(a)h=\begin{pmatrix} 0&ah_1\\bh_2&0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Why does your candidate for the derivative depend on the variable in the limit?

Comment: Sorry I mean $Df(a)h$

Comment: still no, I think you should check your computation of $Df$

Comment: Oh $Df=\begin{pmatrix} D_1f_1&D_2f_1\\D_1f_2&D_1f_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$? and $Df(a)h=\begin{pmatrix} h_2\\h_1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @AColoredReptile that's correct. Sorry for the late response